# Passing forwardRef to React.cloneElement - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have quite difficult idea. Basically I am using useRef() like that

```
const refInput = useRef();
```

and then I am rendering appropriate children depending on the state of the parent passing useRef as a ref

```
{React.cloneElement(children[currentStep - 1], { ref: refInput })}
```

This works. However I am getting warning saying:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

It seems like it is going to work as long as I provide forwardRef for the cloneElement. Anyone know how can I do it?